# Using Euler derive the relationships between cosine and exponential function

Tags: trigonometry, eulers-method

$$\cos\phi=\frac{1}{2}(e^{j\phi} + e^{-j\phi}).$$
Please i was told to do this assignment but cant prove if anyone can help me out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would write out what is $\frac{1}{2}(e^{ix} + e^{-ix})$ using euler's formula, and see if anything cancels. hint: something cancels

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$e^{j\phi}=\cos\phi+j\sin\phi$$